# C# lock with multiple mutual exclusion instead of one

Tags: c#

I have the following C# code,

```
lock(_privateStaticObject)
{
   // My Code
}
```

The problem is that my code can only run by one user at a time. I wanna the same code can be run by 4-5 users but not more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netcore-3.1) for your task

Comment: So I need 
`SemaphoreSlim.Wait()  
// My Code
SemaphoreSlim.Release() `

Comment: [Semaphore and SemaphoreSlim (MS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/threading/semaphore-and-semaphoreslim) & [Semaphore in C# (TutorialsPoint)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Semaphore-in-Chash) & [Threading with Semaphore in C# (C-SharpCorner)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/threading-with-semaphore-in-C-Sharp/)